# Can bargaining game problem be classified as a subcategory of Coalitional and non-coalitional games?

Tags: game-theory

Can bargaining game problem be classified as a subcategory of Coalitional and non-coalitional games? I'm writing a master degree thesis in using cooperative game theory for high voltage transmission expansion planning and I want to classify the games in the most condivisible and accurate way in my prologue.
According to Nash(1950)(1953) bargainings games seems to be a "subcategory" of coalitional and non-coalitional games.
Can you help me?

Comment: Shouldn't a master's degree thesis be your own work? Have you asked your advisor for help?

Comment: sure, it IS my work but  in this area there is not a universal classification, so I cannot see the point of your statement.

Comment: apologies for being rude. I just meant this seems like the kind of question to ask your advisor instead.

Comment: No prob! I understand what you want to say me: in fact I'd be best if I explain better my problem!